How to avoid return code=120 in my HLASM "Hello World"?
I have a simple HLASM "Hello world" program on z/VSE.
It links and compiles successfully.
It also sends expected "Hello world" message to operator console, but ends with return code =120.
Appreciate any advice why it finishes abnormally? How to correct that?
Below is the job with the source code:
* $$ JOB JNM=CRASMHEL,DISP=D,CLASS=A,NTFY=YES
* $$ LST DISP=D,CLASS=A,PRI=3
// JOB CRASMHEL COMPILE PROGRAM COBTEST
// ASSGN SYSLST,PRT1
// OPTION ERRS,SXREF,SYM,NODECK,LINK    
// EXEC ASMA90,SIZE=(ASMA90,64K),PARM='EXIT(LIBEXIT(EDECKXIT)),SIZE(MAXC
               -200K,ABOVE)'
HELLO    CSECT
         STM   14,12,12(13)       Save registers
         LR    12,15              Establish addressability
         USING HELLO,12
         WTO   'HELLO, WORLD'     Write to operator
         LM    14,12,12(13)       Restore registers
         BR    14                 Return
         END   HELLO
/*
// EXEC LNKEDT,SIZE=256K
// EXEC
/&
* $$ EOJ


Presumably you need to return a value via whatever the normal means are. From a quick google try xr 15, 15.

Thank you Jester, I see that in IBM provided sample, it done by
sr    15,15

Does not really matter as long as you zero r15

Looks like I did not do save/restore registers correctly.
Below is working version, I made from ASMMSAMP sample provided by IBM:
asmmsamp csect                                         
saveregs stm   14,12,12(13) Save caller's registers 
         lr    12,15        Load our base register    
         using asmmsamp,12  Establish addressability  
         la    14,rsa       Address of our save area  
         st    13,4(,14)    Save caller's save area address              
         st    14,8(,13)    and our save area address in caller's       
*                             save area                                 
setr13   lr    13,14        From now on, use our save area               
*---------------------------------------------------------------------  
*        do something                                                   
*---------------------------------------------------------------------  
         WTO   'Hello World'
*---------------------------------------------------------------------  
*        cleanup and exit                                               
*---------------------------------------------------------------------  
exit_ok  l     13,4(,13)    Address of caller's save area                
         lm    14,12,12(13) Restore registers                           
         sr    15,15        Set return code to zero                      
         br    14            and return.                                

RSA      dc    18f'0'        Standard save area                         
         end
/*
// EXEC LNKEDT,SIZE=256K
// EXEC
/&
* $$ EOJ

